# SQL Async Multiple Queries Combine Results -- Maximum Results (Top XYZ)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a search function set up, where I run multiple queries simultaneously. The top 1000 results of each query are written to a table.  (These run async--I am just leaving out the code that I am using to do that)

```
Insert into Results
Select Top 1000 Text from A where Contains(Text,'"searchString"')

Insert into Results
Select Top 1000 Text from B where Contains(Text,'"searchString"')

Insert into Results
Select Top 1000 Text from C where Contains(Text,'"searchString"')
```

Then, I select the top 1000 results from that table.

```
Select Top 1000 * from Results
```

Would there be a good way to efficiently check, at any point earlier in the process, if there are already 1000 results, and, if there are, cancelling the other queries and selecting the 1000 results ASAP.

Comment: Do you not care which 1,000 records you get? `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is not deterministic. Also should the third query be `C`?

Comment: The above statement is NOT Async. The SELECT statments are processed sequentially. However you may be calling it asyncronously. If so it would be better to use the Async framework in net 4.0 / 4.5

Comment: Yes, I know. I am not clear in my question

Comment: Those queries DO run async.  I generate them dynamically, then pass the text to an `ExecAsync` stored procedure that we have written.  Approx 3000 queries will be running once this is up and going--I just left that out of the code and mentioned the async in the title

Comment: How do you generate them dynamically?  In .NET?   Since 1000 is not a lot of IO I would recommend .NET TPL as it will parallel and sum.  This is a pattern used in Azure table storage for parallel query of multiple partition keys.   I don't think you are going to get a concurrent sum in TSQL or SP.

Comment: They all execute via a stored procedure.  The user passes in a list of tables (essentially) and a transaction id.  The only thing "dynamic" is the table name and (I left this part out of the code I showed) a transaction id that goes along with each row inserted into the results table.  That way multiple people can search simultaneously

Comment: Also--if I go over 100 results it isn't a huge deal.  I just want to speed things up.  Nothing more.

Comment: Finally, nope I don't care about which results I get, hence the no order by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will likely give you a plan that achieves your desired result of not processing any rows after the 1,000th one has been found.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT Text
         FROM   A
         WHERE  CONTAINS(Text, '"searchString"')
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Text
         FROM   B
         WHERE  CONTAINS(Text, '"searchString"')
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Text
         FROM   C
         WHERE  CONTAINS(Text, '"searchString"'))
INSERT INTO Results
SELECT TOP 1000 Text
FROM   CTE
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I agree. My concern with that (and what I mention in the title but not my question) is that I have these queries executing--not how they are written above, but asynchronously.  ~3000 queries run simultaneously and then write to the results table.  (I use a stored procedure we have set up to accomplish this...)

Comment: Martin since that is a slick answer to the question as stated at the time I will give you a +1.

Comment: Agreed.  I will definitely be looking at that in the future

Answer (score 1):

If you setup your result table with an identity column you can achieve your goal using this query (let 'counter' be that column. don't forget to put an index on it)

```
declare @remaining int
select @remaining = 1000 - (max(counter) - min(counter) + 1) from result
if @result>0
  insert into Result (Text) select top (@remaining) Text from MyTable
```

Also, if you have a list of table names, you can use a while loop and exit if @result is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL limits the number of rows to 4 from any subsequent query

SET ROWCOUNT 4

SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

Get the number of rows form the preceeding select

so something like

SELECT TOP etc...

SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

SET ROWCOUNT 1000 - @Rows

Will probably error if @row goes below zero

but you an trap this with IF and goto PROC_LABLE

Comment: SET ROWCOUNT is not recommended to limit the number of rows returned, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms189463.aspx

Comment: Agreed Top N does the job, but use of this depends on which version of MS SQL you are using: The N is not a programmable variable in earlier versions of MS SQL. Your link says what top does however of a better link comparing the two: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Comment: My link should have explained why SET ROWCOUNT is not recommended. But thanks for your link anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into #tt2 
SELECT TOP 1000 [sID]
FROM [docSVsys]
where (select count(*) from #tt2) < 1000
```

But I would still use .NET and TPL.

This will still process all tables but it should process 0 rows once it gets to 1000