# Possible to get faster than Full-Text Search?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Async Multiple Queries Combine Results — Maximum Results (Top XYZ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310177/sql-async-multiple-queries-combine-results-maximum-results-top-xyz)

I have thousands of tables, essentially named like this:

```
Table_key1_key2_key3
```

and structured like this:

```
ID
TextColumn
```

There is a full-text index on the text column, and each table has its own full text catalog.

I have a stored procedure that generates queries for these tables, when the user passes in a bunch of (key1,key2,key3) tuples and search text.  I fire off a bunch of async queries, which search the `TextColumn`s and writes the results to a table.  Once they all finish, I select the top 1000 matching results.  (I also have added code so that every time 100 finish, I check the results table and if there are more than 1000 results, I return)

The problem with this is that it is still too slow, especially when there are few-to-no matches...).  We have *many, many, many* rows and users will often search with ~5,000 (key1,key2,key3) tuples selected.  Is there any good way that I could speed this up further?  I have full access to the entire table structure, etc.

Comment: Put the bits of text you are searching for in their own columns...

Comment: The text that I am searching is free text, and the search is to be a "contains" type of search.  would it be faster to chop up the TextColumn into multiple columns?  And I thought I was limited to one FTI per table?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an RDBMS for something like this. You're far better off deploying a distributed solution such as ElasticSearch or Solr that allows you to search massive document repositories using methods far more flexible than what full-text search provides.

Comment: What does that routing framework have to do with the question?

Comment: @Blam, It was written by the guy who posted the answer. Bordering on naughty in  my opinion...